# Comparative or superlative adjective?

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, superlative-degree

```
I think it is best not to be impolite.
```

Is the above sentence fine, or should it have `better` instead of `best` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct.
In Oxford English Dictionary one of the meanings of BEST is "most appropriate, advantageous, or well advised". 
Compare your sentence with the following: it's best if we both go.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is correct.  I don't see much difference between that and

```
I think it is not to be impolite.
```

It is not either/or because both essentially have the same meaning, though the use of **best** is a little stronger than **better**.